# app.get with multiple arguments - e.g. app.get('/', requireAuth, (req, res) => { })

Tags: react-native, express, routes, middleware

I am wondering how express.js works when you specify multiple argument in the app.get, for example:

```
app.get('/', requireAuth, (req, res) => { })
```

Here, I believe you have the slash "/" as the route, and (req, res) as arguments for the callback function. But there is also the 'requireAuth' part which was used for authorization. But in the documentation I don't find anything about multiple arguments in the way we use 'requireAuth' now. It does mention that you can use an array of functions but that is not used here (https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). How does it work?

P.S. The 'requireAuth' code for reference:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  const { authorization } = req.headers;
  // authorization === 'Bearer laksjdflaksdjasdfklj'

  if (!authorization) {
    return res.status(401).send({ error: 'You must be logged in.' });
  }

  const token = authorization.replace('Bearer ', '');
  jwt.verify(token, 'MY_SECRET_KEY', async (err, payload) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).send({ error: 'You must be logged in.' });
    }

    const { userId } = payload;

    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the arguments are simply middle-ware functions that you call before the actual route logic is run(for individual routes). As long as there is next handling in each of the middle-ware functions, the chain will run till your route logic, and then exit where next isn't handled.

This is the magic of express. You can do many things with it, like error handling, handling different content types etc.